# How to find ALL word that have X amount of characters?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a code that finds all words that have 4 (in this case) characters. So my expected output would be `this that abcd`

My current code looks like this, the problem with it, it's only finding the first word `this` and it stops looking for further `that abcd` it.

```
let string = 'aa this bb cc that abcd';
function longWord(str) {
  let words = str.split(' ');
  let longWord = '';
  for (let word of words) {
    if (word.length > longWord.length) longWord = word;
  }
  return longWord;
}
console.log(longWord(string));
```

From my understanding i need to include a loop.

Change from `for (let word of words) {`

To this `for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {`

But then after this i'm lost :(

Looking at google i'm able to find only code with similar to mine or outputting a char number.

Comment: create an array and keep pushing the results and finally return that array.

Comment: `split` at `" "` and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the resulting array based on `length`

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt That's horrible, why not just use a split and then filter? Like this: `string.split(' ').filter(word => word.length === 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` with `filter` like so.

`split` will create an array of strings seperated by space. `filter` will return only strings with `length` of 4 characters. Finally, `join` will return the array as space seperated strings.

```js
let string = 'aa this bb cc that abcd';

function longWord(str) {
    return str.split(' ').filter(x => x.length === 4).join(' ');
}

console.log(longWord(string));
```

Comment: Should be `str.split(' ')`, not `string.split(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

There you go

- `split`: create an array with all the words
- `filter`: get only the words with 4 chars
- `join`: create a string with all elements splitted with a space

  `var el = string.split(' ').filter(x => x.length == 4).join(' ');`

Comment: Your answer is right, but could be better with a code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, it deleted my code snippet when I tried to add the list. Thank you for the edit @Koby Douek.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.split(' ').filter(x => x.length === 4).map(x => x)
```

This piece of code should give you the expected output

Comment: Why is `map` required?

Comment: I think that this is an incomplete answer. Your result produce an array not a string as @Marius was asking and map is not required.

Comment: You are right, the answer only serves as a base but from here it shouldn't be too hard to join the strings together

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly there are two tasks:
1. find the largest character count for a word in the string, and
2. find all the words that match this count

```
const longestWords = str => {
    const words = str.split(/\s+/g);
    const maxCount = Math.max.apply( null, words.map( word => word.length ));
    return words.filter( word => word.length === maxCount );
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pkxwfmb2/

```
console.log( longestWords("aa this bb cc that abcd") );
// [ "this", "that", "abcd" ]
console.log( longestWords("aa this bb cc that abcdef") );
// [ "abcdef" ]
console.log( longestWords("a bb c dd e f gg") );
// [ "bb", "dd", "gg" ]
```

Comment: Yeah, nothing in the original question says 4 is the desired character count to be found, it just so happens this is the largest count in the example string. So hard-coding `4` into the solution makes little sense.

Comment: Your code looks so much better this is what i was trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/MariuzM/9gtyevm4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let string = 'aa this bb cc that abcd';
function longWord(str) {
    let words = str.split(' ');
    let output = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length == 4)
            output.push(words[i]);
    }
    return output.join(',');
}
console.log(longWord(string));
```

You'll get your expected output.